# How to make a sql query that accept both option in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm just wondering how can I modify this query so that I can search using either with my Song name or the song number.

I know I can change :number to :title after LIKE in my query but I'm just wondering how can I modify it so that It would be able to accept both option.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
<?php
  require_once '../config.php';

  if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $inpText = $_POST['query'];
    $sql = '(SELECT id, title, number, chord FROM Song WHERE number LIKE :number)';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['number' => '%' . $inpText . '%']);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  
    echo'<table>';
    if ($result) {
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='page/details.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['title']} <br> </a></td>";
        echo "<td><a style='margin-left:10px'>{$row['chord']}   <br> </a></td>";
      }
    } else {
    }
    echo'</table>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: You do realize that `number LIKE '%1%'` etc. will match _any_ number with "1" in them: 12, 21, 100, 411, etc.

Comment: Its not totally clear what you are asking here. Do you want to do `WHERE number LIKE :number OR title LIKE :title` or do you want to be able to run a query that searches the `number` column when you are passed a number or the `title` column when you are passed a title? So changing `WHERE number` to `WHERE title`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `OR` on your query, e.g:

```sql
SELECT
    id, title, number, chord
FROM
    Song
WHERE
    number LIKE :number OR title LIKE :title
```

Here's a tutorial about it: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_and_or.asp

On your PHP code you also need to change to something like:

```php
$inpText = $_POST['query'];
$inpTitle = $_POST['title'];
// ...

$stmt->execute([
    'number' => '%' . $inpText . '%',
    'title' => '%' . $titleInput . '%'
]);

// ...
```